Updating selenium webdriver to latest(4.25.0) is giving an error desiredcapabilities is inaccessible due to its protection level
Following code is no more working after updating Selenium WebDriver to latest (4.25.0)
DesiredCapabilities dc=new DesiredCapabilities();
dc.SetCapability("app","exe path");
driver=new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:1000"),dc);

Getting DesiredCapacility is inaccessible due to protection level. Can someone help me in resolving the issue?
Downgrading Selenium WebDriver to 3.14.0 is working but need to make it working with latest version
Thanks,
Swathi

geckodriver here?  I believe you'll want to create a new FireFoxProfile(), and then use profile.setPreference.   For a list of some of those preferences check here: https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/testing/geckodriver/src/prefs.rs
